# Change rails default cookie expiration time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies, ruby-on-rails-4

I know how to change the expiration time when saving a cookie, what I would like to know is how to change the **default value**.
I have a lot of sentences that set cookies scattered around my code and I have to change **all of them** to expire after 30 days, so I would prefer to just change something that sets the default expiration time to 30 days so that it affects all cookies everywhere.
Thanks in advance!

Update
Tried using:

```
# config/initializers/session_store.rb
MyApp::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_your_app_session', expire_after: 30.days
```

But still doesn't works... I think I know what the problem is. When I set the cookie expiration at the moment I save it, it then appears under "Response Cookies" on both Firefox and Chrome (that's when it works) But the rest of the cookies appear under "Request Cookies" on both explorers. The thing is that I don't know how the Request/Response thing is handled by rails.

This is how I save my cookies, which doesn't work.

```
cookies[:region] = params[:region]
```

And this is how I made it work, but would prefer the other way to save time and make it easier to edit in the future.

```
cookies[:region] = { value: params[:region], expires: 30.days.from_now }
```

Update 2: Created a new rails app to show the problem isolated: https://github.com/jafuentest/newapp

Comment: Can you make a minimal Rails app (in this case only a controller) showing the issue you're having, and put the link in the question?

Comment: Done, you can view it here: https://github.com/jafuentest/newapp

Answer (score 1):

You can save it in session_store:

```
# config/initializers/session_store.rb
MyApp::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_your_app_session', expire_after: 30.days
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks your help, I think it works but I'm missing something.. On chrome "Inspect Element" menu, the expiration date is 30 days from now. But if I close the browser and open it again, the values that are loaded from cookies appear blank again. Any ideas?

Comment: I used `cookies[:region] = { value: params[:region], expires: 30.days.from_now }` and it worked, so it's not the browser's fault. Any other ideas?

Comment: I tried going back to rails 3 and still nothing. I think the problem is not with the code you gave me, I think it's something else.. I updated the question with a better explanation of what's happening.

Comment: Sorry if I'm asking again, but did you change `MyApp::Application` with the real name of your application?

Comment: Yeah that part is ok.